# Bash script Issue parsing text in line with whitespace characters

Tags: bash, read, whitespace, line

I have a list of commands to parse through for an audit, similar to this:

```
1. -a *policy name=PolicyName -a *policy workflow name=PolicyWorkflow -a *policy action name=PolicyAction -s Server -b Storage -J Node -y 1 Months -o -F -S
2. -a *policy name=PolicyName -a *policy workflow name=PolicyWorkflow -a *policy action name=PolicyAction -s Server -b Storage -J Node -y 1 Months -o -F -S
3. -a *policy name=Policy Name -a *policy workflow name=PolicyWorkflow -a *policy action name=PolicyAction -s Server -b Storage -J Node -y 1 Months -o -F -S
```

I'm trying to set each of the `name=Value` to variables. As this is a standard pattern, i used read with success, however when I get to a line with whitespace (see line 3), it offsets all my variables. I'm unsure how to tackle this without looping through each word in the line and matching specific patterns. Hoping someone would have a better solution out there.

Comment: You could just use sed to replace all instances of 'Policy Name' with PolicyName prior to using read, e.g. `sed 's/Policy Name/PolicyName/g' <Input_file> | while read ...`

Comment: @Warwick Only if the whitespace is unimportant and the policy name is actually "Policy Name" and not just a placeholder for an actual policy name that the poster inserted to show the general pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `bash` and using an array variable instead, you can do something like:

```
{ IFS=$'\n'; array=($(grep -Po 'name=[^-]+(?=\s*-)' infile)); }
```

then print the elements of the array (array Index in bash starts from 0):

```
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
name=PolicyName
name=PolicyWorkflow
name=PolicyAction
name=PolicyName
name=PolicyWorkflow
name=PolicyAction
name=Policy Name
name=PolicyWorkflow
name=PolicyAction
```

Or to print just a single element:

```
printf '%s\n' "${array[6]}"
name=Policy Name
```

- We defined [`IFS`](/a/16195/72456) to "`\n`ewline" character `IFS=$'\n'` so that [the word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) will happen on "`\n`ewline" character only on the result of [unquoted](/a/78924/72456)–[Command Substitution `$(...)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).
- The syntax `{ list; }` is known [Grouping Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) and I just used to grouping my commands.
- The `array=(...)` syntax is used to creating an associated [array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) variable named `array`.
- With `grep -Po 'name=[^-]+(?=\s*-)' infile`, we print `-o`nly the matches that matches the pattern *`"name="`* followed by any non-zero length of characters but a hyphen `[^-]+` which follows by zero-or-more whitespaces until a hyphen `(?=\s*-)`.

  - The syntax `(?=...)` is [positive-lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups) and with grep's `-P` option it's can be use to interpret the pattern as a [Perl-Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE)](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#index-_002d_002dperl_002dregexp).

---

**Future reading:**

- [How to add/remove an element to/from the array in bash?](/q/328882/72456)
- [Is it a sane approach to “back up” the $IFS variable?](/q/264926/72456)

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, thank you.

Comment: @JustinDavis I added some explanations if you were interested to know what is happening.